# Haskell Stack and C Libraries II

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi, haskell-stack

This is a follow-up of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701443/haskell-stack-and-c-libraries/34702095#34702095) (unfortunately).

I am trying to `stack build` a project where `Main.hs` has some FFI calls to a proprietary C library, `libMyLib.so`, located in `/usr/local/lib` (which is included in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

When run in GHCi (outside `stack`) with the command `ghci /usr/local/lib/ -lMyLib`, everything works fine.

However when running `stack build`, I have a linking-related issue :

```
me@user:~/myproject$ stack build

myproject-0.1.0.0: build
Preprocessing library myproject-0.1.0.0...
In-place registering myproject-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'myproject-exe' for myproject-0.1.0.0...
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/myproject-exe/myproject-exe ...
/usr/bin/ld: .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/myproject-exe/myproject-exe-tmp/Main.o: undefined reference to symbol 'mycfunction'
/usr/local/lib/libMyLib.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

--  While building package myproject-0.1.0.0 using:
      /home/me/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build lib:myproject exe:myproject-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Here is an extra of the associated cabal file:

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  extra-libraries:     MyLib

executable myproject-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base, bytestring, safe, split
                     , myproject
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Running `stack exec env` shows that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` points to the right directory (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`), and just to make sure I have added this directory to the `.yaml` file (`extra-lib-dirs: [/usr/local/lib]`).

I have played with various GCC compile options, e.g. `-pthread` instead of `-threaded`..., via the `.cabal` file parameters or directly via `stack build` (`stack build --ghc-options="-foo..."`), but to no avail.

**My question:** where else should I look? What kind of test should I run to find the origin of the issue (apparent linking problem)?

== EDIT ==
There were two versions of the same C library installed, and one has a dependency on another C library, say `libOther.so`. 
When I finally realized that, I added it to the cabal file and that worked fine :

```
extra-libraries:     Other, MyLib
```

Comment: Can you increase verbosity of the build? LD_LIBRARY_PATH has nothing to do with linking and only adds confusion. I recommend using `-rpath` instead. Your linker command needs to get `-L /usr/local/lib` but this doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: A guess: `stack build --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/lib`. Does that work ?

Comment: @n.m and Sibi thanks for your suggestions. I tried as recommended but without success. But I finally got to the bottom of it : I needed to add an extra library dependency, which I'll describe in an edit.

Comment: Hmm. "needed to add an extra library dependency" — that's what I thought initially and commented to that effect. Deleted the comment because something about it seemed wrong.

Comment: Why don't you answer the question yourself instead of the edit ?

Comment: @JeanAnthelme you should post the solution you found as an answer and accept it so this question falls out of the "unanswered" queue.